# Why does passing arrays of non-const members to functions receiving them as const generate compiler warnings?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, constants, const-correctness

Say I create an array of pointers to a data structure `ds`:

```
struct ds *arr[2];
arr[0] = new_ds();
arr[1] = new_ds();
```

If I were to create a routine that takes `arr` but doesn't modify the array [of pointers] nor the contents pointed by the array members, I would do something like:

```
void read_only(struct ds const * const *arr);
```

That is, it takes a pointer to [the beggining of an array of] constant pointers to constant structs ds. However, that leads to compiler warnings when calling with `arr`:

```
note: expected ‘const struct ds * const*’ but argument is of type ‘struct ds **’
```

Which doesn't happen when just passing pointers around:

```
void ro(struct ds const *i);
ro(arr[0]);
// No warnings!
```

Why is that? Is the array case somehow "unsafe"? Of course I could "fix" it casting to const, but if my arrays and their contents are never const, that would lead to a lot of compiler warnings followed by modifications to cast things. Is there a way around this? Am I getting some concept wrong?

Even if I do something like

```
void ro(struct ds const * const i);
```

Which doesn't even make much sense (constant copy), the compiler doesn't complain when passing `arr[0]`.

Comment: You can't pass a `T **` to a function expecting `const T **` because this could lead to problems: you could re-point the second-level pointer to a with a  seemingly mutable type to and immutable object and use that pointer to mutate the immutable object – without a type error.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: But the second-level pointer is also constant, there is no way to re-point it. It would lead to `error: assignment of read-only location` compiler **error**.

Comment: @J.Doe in `T **`, the second-level pointer is not constant, and that's what matters.

Comment: @J.Doe, the closest you can get to preserve `const` is to declare the receiving function something like `void prn_ds (const void *a, size_t n)`.  (where `a` is your `arr`) Then within the receiving function `struct ds * const *b = (struct ds * const *)a;`. Then you can operate on the array with `const` preserved. (e.g. `printf (" size: %zu  word: %s\n", b[i]->sz, b[i]->word);` )

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The question was marked as duplicate, I did not close it nor did I get my answer. As I pointed out in the comments I do not think it's the same case as in the question marked as a duplicate of this one, though ThePragmaticCroissant says it is (I can't understand his explanation in the comments).

Comment: Sorry, I saw that, I think the duplicate is a cheezy answer. Here is something that might help [example](http://pastebin.com/S5kRNkfi).